# phpstan: how to handle derived class return types

Tags: php, phpstan

What's the right way to fix the error generated by `phpstan` for this sample code?  The error message is:

`Method Foo::foo() should return Child but returns Base.`

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

Interface MyI {abstract function a(): self;}
Class Base implements MyI { 
    public function a(): self {return $this;} 
}
Class Child extends Base { 
    public function c(): self {return $this;} 
}
Class Foo {
public function factory(): Child {return new Child();}
/**
 * @return Child
 */
public function foo() /* note no return type */  {
    return $this->factory()
        ->c()
        ->a();
}
```

}

One way to eliminate the error is to change the `@return` to read:

```
/**
 * @return Child | Base
 */
```

But I greatly dislike that because `foo()` *never* returns an instance of `Base`.  The code only ever works with the derived class `Child`.  In fact, the interface and base classes are both in a library (dependency), so I mostly cannot even change that code.

I could re-implement `a()` in my `Child` class like this:

```
    public function a(): Child {
        parent::a();
        return $this;
    }
```

But that is also ugly, and worse, this is a toy example.  In the real class, I'd have to re-implement many methods.  Very bad.

Comment: Hi, it's best to ask these questions on PHPStan's GitHub: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `@return static` for that: https://phpstan.org/r/42ee409c-ada2-44c9-a26d-6a85c2327bca

To learn about all different PHPDoc posibilities head to PHPStan documentation:

- https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdocs-basics
- https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types

Comment: I'm unable to modify the code in the `Base` class -- without cloning and making unique the open-source library I'm using.

Comment: You can use stub files for that to override the PHPDoc: https://phpstan.org/user-guide/stub-files

Answer (score 0):

Had something similar too, although my case was a bit different.

My code was:

```
trait X
{
    protected function createFoo(string $childClassName): BaseClass
    {
        // do something...

        return $childClassName::createFrom($this);
    }
}
```

And I was getting the same error as OP:

```
public function bar(): ChildClass
{
    return $this->createFoo(ChildClass::class);
        // phpstan error: Method bar() should return Child but returns Base
}
```

After reading briefly about [phpstan generics](https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-in-php-using-phpdocs), ended up with the following phpdoc. Seems to solve the issue the right way:

```
trait X
{
    /**
     * @template T of BaseClass
     * @param class-string<T> $childClassName
     * @return T
     */
    protected function createFoo(string $childClassName): BaseClass
    {
        // do something...

        return $childClassName::createFrom($this);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.